# С помощью чего можно достичь данный эффект

Tags: javascript, resize, z-index

Столкнулся с такой страничкой http://www.adhamdannaway.com/ понравилась задумка c изменением картинки автора(по умолчание изображения делят экран на две половины, при работе с мышкой одно изображение перекрывает другое), но моего маленького стека не хватает для реализации.Есть идеи что, эффект создается за счет js при наведении курсора меняется размер блока с картинкой и его z-index.
Но на практике не могу реализовать, буду благодарен за помощь, а так же ссылки на примеры?

Comment: Вы бы хоть уточнили, что за задумка. Что пробовали, что не получилось?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko это не все неопытности, долго формулирую правильность вопроса чтобы другие поняли.Поправил текст, надеюсь понятнее стало.К слову что пробовал.В голове идеи есть, но реализация хромает. А с js учусь поэтому  хотел бы примеры  похожие получить или пару советов.
Задача видимо не моего еще уровня, но понимания  и желание сделать огромное,поэтому решил обратиться за помощью

Comment: Есть готовые библиотеки, можете посмотреть, как там реализовано. Или, если хотите сами, то ничего сложного - изменяете размер картинок при движении мышкой.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо.
насчет библиотек был бы рад есди бы скинули похожий вариант.
Да и если писать самому  больше вопросов возникает ,поэтому опять же просил  примеры для разбора

Comment: Можете посмотреть например здесь https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp . Или гуглить по запросу **js image comparison**

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko спасибо то что надо, чутка доработать и получиться то что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете посмотреть например здесь w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp .

Или гуглить по запросу **js image comparison**

```js
function initComparisons() {
  var x, i;
  /* Find all elements with an "overlay" class: */
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("img-comp-overlay");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    /* Once for each "overlay" element:
    pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function: */
    compareImages(x[i]);
  }

  function compareImages(img) {
    var slider, img, clicked = 0,
      w, h;
    /* Get the width and height of the img element */
    w = img.offsetWidth;
    h = img.offsetHeight;
    /* Set the width of the img element to 50%: */
    img.style.width = (w / 2) + "px";
    /* Create slider: */
    slider = document.createElement("DIV");
    slider.setAttribute("class", "img-comp-slider");
    /* Insert slider */
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
    /* Position the slider in the middle: */
    slider.style.top = (h / 2) - (slider.offsetHeight / 2) + "px";
    slider.style.left = (w / 2) - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    /* Execute a function when the mouse button is pressed: */
    slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
    /* And another function when the mouse button is released: */
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
    /* Or touched (for touch screens: */
    slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
    /* And released (for touch screens: */
    window.addEventListener("touchstop", slideFinish);

    function slideReady(e) {
      /* Prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image: */
      e.preventDefault();
      /* The slider is now clicked and ready to move: */
      clicked = 1;
      /* Execute a function when the slider is moved: */
      window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
      window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
    }

    function slideFinish() {
      /* The slider is no longer clicked: */
      clicked = 0;
    }

    function slideMove(e) {
      var pos;
      /* If the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function: */
      if (clicked == 0) return false;
      /* Get the cursor's x position: */
      pos = getCursorPos(e)
      /* Prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image: */
      if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
      if (pos > w) pos = w;
      /* Execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor: */
      slide(pos);
    }

    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /* Get the x positions of the image: */
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /* Calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image: */
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      /* Consider any page scrolling: */
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      return x;
    }

    function slide(x) {
      /* Resize the image: */
      img.style.width = x + "px";
      /* Position the slider: */
      slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - (slider.offsetWidth / 2) + "px";
    }
  }
}

initComparisons();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.img-comp-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  /*should be the same height as the images*/
}

.img-comp-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-comp-img img {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.img-comp-slider {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  opacity: 0.7;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-comp-container">
  <div class="img-comp-img">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_forest.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="img-comp-img img-comp-overlay">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_snow.jpg" width="300" height="200">
  </div>
</div>
```